# Android Java Set OnClick to a ImageView within multiple nested tags

Tags: java, android, xml, android-toolbar, android-appbarlayout

Hi everyone I'm trying to create a menu that comes down when clicking on the profile picture:

[image]

but as you can see that ImageView is inside a cardView which is in turn inside a tool bar and as the initial parent I have an App Bar layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    >


    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/primaryPopHome"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.bar"
            >


            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"


                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:src="@drawable/poplogo"

                />


            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="300dp"
                android:innerRadius="0dp"
                android:shape="ring"
                android:thicknessRatio="1.9"
                app:cardCornerRadius="80dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_profilomain"
                    android:layout_width="42dp"
                    android:layout_height="42dp"

                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"

                    />
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionMenuView
        android:id="@+id/mnuItem"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:background="@color/def2"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        />


    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/add_fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/poplike"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/redButton2"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <!--Floating action button for add alarm-->
    <!--Make sure that you are constraining this
        button to the parent button-->
    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/add_alarm_fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/add_fab"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/add_fab"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/add_fab"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_24"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/redButton2"
        />

    <!--Action name text for the add alarm button-->
    <!--Make sure that you are constraining this Text to
        the add Alarm FAB button-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/add_alarm_action_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Crea Post"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/add_alarm_fab"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/add_alarm_fab"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/add_alarm_fab" />

    <!--Floating action button for add person-->
    <!--Make sure that you are constraining this
        button to the add Alarm FAB button-->
    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/add_person_fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/add_alarm_fab"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/add_alarm_fab"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/add_alarm_fab"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_search_24"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/redButton2"
        />

    <!--Action name text for the add person button-->
    <!--Make sure that you are constraining this Text
        to the add Person FAB button-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/add_person_action_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Cerca utenti"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/add_person_fab"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/add_person_fab"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/add_person_fab" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_logout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="152dp"
        android:text="Logout"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/appBarLayout"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.111" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rcViewPostMain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appBarLayout"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-16dp" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I tried to set an OnClick listener from the java code but when I go to run the app the onclick doesn't work when I click on the image:

```
 ImageView img_profilo = findViewById(R.id.img_profilomain);

        img_profilo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "d", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mnuItem.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
```

I tried to do it with the toolbar too but it doesn't work anyway:

```
tlb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "sad", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Edit:
It doesn't work with this either

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

                if(item.getItemId() == R.id.img_profilomain)
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "wds", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Would anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
                    return true;
                }
            });

Comment: access it from menu

Comment: @RohitKumar It does not work, in fact when I click the toast does not appear (see the update of my question with your code)

Comment: add some code on menuItem click

Comment: if(item.getItemId() == R.id.img_profilomain){

Comment: @RohitKumar It still doesn't show the toast even when I click the image. ImagevIew are just images that are inside the cardview, toolbar and appbarlayout tags. I did not declare the items from code

Comment: toolbar.findViewById(R.id.img_profilomain).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "wds", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

Comment: @RohitKumar It doesn't work with any kind of onlick or itemonclick